# EPPlus not Inserting Formula Correcty

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm using EPPlus to manipulate an Excel file. I need to insert a formula that references an entire column. I'm currently using:

```
currentWorksheet.Cells[2, 4].Formula = "QUARTILE(C:C,1)";
```

If I manually enter this formula into the Excel sheet it works, or if I insert it with a finite range in EPPlus like so:

```
=QUARTILE(C2:C1000,1)
```

But when it's inserted as a whole column range of C:C using EPPlus it results in the following:

```
=QUARTILE(#REF!,1)
```

Is there something special needed when referencing entire columns, or is this just a bug in EPPlus?

Comment: I can't recreate this - when i do this in a new workbook the formula is correct. With the exact foumula above pasted in. Is there some oddity with cells being merged or deleted or something? Perhaps if the outputed spreadsheet doesnt contain sensitive info you could post it somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

You can use following code

```
worksheet.Cells["A1"].Formula= "=QUARTILE(C2:C1000,1)";
```

Answer (score 2):

Stewart is correct in that the formula should be valid.  Try pasting in the rest of your code.  I thought together a quick unit test and it worked fine:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Quartile_Range_Test()
{
    //Throw in some data
    var dtMain = new DataTable("tblData");
    dtMain.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(int)));

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var row = dtMain.NewRow();
        row["Col1"] = i * 100;
        dtMain.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    //Clear the file
    var newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\Temp.xlsx");
    if (newFile.Exists)
        newFile.Delete();

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
    {
        var currentWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");
        currentWorksheet.Cells["C1"].LoadFromDataTable(dtMain, false);
        currentWorksheet.Cells[2, 4].Formula = "QUARTILE(C:C,1)";

        package.Save();

    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't answering the question. Surely its better to wait for the OP to clarify what the problem is than to verify you couldn't recreate it and post it as an answer?

Comment: @Stewart_R - Seriously, a downvote?  If no one can reproduce the problem (no other responses so far) them paste a working example so the OP can compare with.  We cant paste the above code into a comment since it would be too long.  So, our only choice is a full blown answer.  Which could help someone else down the road.  WOW

Comment: I think my comment is valid (answers should be answers, no? The unit test confirming you couldnt recreate the OPs problem doesn't add any value IMHO). I have no comment on the validity of an anonymous downvote.